# Angular, pass a value from model html to Controller

Tags: angularjs

newbie question: How can i pass a value from my HTML back to the Controller code:
FOr example, I want to pass the value '1234' to my js code.

```
<div ng-app="Test">    
      <div ng-controller="myCntlr">
             <div ng-model="myModel" value="1234">
             {{outputVal}}
            </div>
      </div>     
</div>
```

JS controller:

```
test.controller('myCntlr', function ($scope, $filter) {

    // access the value '1234' here ?
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can set the `value` to be a variable, `value="{{variable}}"` , and you'll have access to that variable in the controller: `$scope.variable = 1234`

Comment: [`ng-init`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit) or write a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Thanks, i think i'll use a directive. :)

Comment: @29er did you get the issue solved?